# Add lines to Datagridview immediately

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, datagridview, windows-forms-designer

I have a DatagridView and I want to add new lines to it. The new lines should appear immediately in GUI.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{               
    dataGridView1.DataSource = Class1.ds.Tables[0];
    String str = "INSERT INTO workers(Worker_Id," +
        "Salary, Work_Hours, Worker_Tel, Worker_Name) " + 
        "VALUES('" + Worker_Id_TB.Text + "','" + 
        int.Parse(Salary_TB.Text) + "','" + 
        int.Parse(Work_Hours_TB.Text) + "','" + Tel_TB.Text + "','" +  
        Worker_Name_TB.Text + "')";
    Class1.GetDataSet(str);
}
```

Comment: Can you show us what you tried so far?

Comment: Please provide a lot more detail with code examples of what you have so far.  There are many ways to do this and it all depends on what you have so far with code examples for what way would work with your code.

Comment: Edited now for you

Comment: The [MS Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/windows-forms-data-binding?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) site has many many great articles on how your Data Provider tools work (and none of them will show gluing data into a string to make a query).

Comment: Couldn't find it in the site. Can you help?

Comment: Add 3 rows to the datatable. The INSERT query in your code is a) irrelevant and b) prone to SQL injection hacking. Read http://bobby-tables.com

Comment: The  code works, I just need to see the changes I do straight away

Answer (score 0):

If your Class1 code is working, you might try adding a BindingSource control to the Windows Form that contains the DataGridView.  Then,

```
   bindingSource1.DataSource = Class1.ds.Tables[0];
   
   dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource1;

   String str = "INSERT INTO ...  ";

   Class1.GetDataSet(str);  [before executing the sql command in this code, you should probably do "bindingSource1.EndEdit()"]
```

If your Class1 code still doesn't produce the desired new data in the DGV, you can look into creating and using Fill() or InsertQuery() sql queries that can be defined in the DataSet.DataTable's DataTableAdapter in Design mode.  In addition, learning to create and add new DataRow objects to a DataTable programmatically might be helpful.
If the DGV data-binding is correct, then updating the datatable should update the dataGridView as well.

If you need more help, please show us the Class1 code.